# Playwright c# how to verify alerts

Tags: c#, alert, playwright

Im trying to verify that an alert has appeared and then verify its text content using playwright c#

The alert contains text from two fields in the app and is displayed on pressing a save button

[image]

```
Page.Dialog += (_, dialog) =>  dialog.AcceptAsync();
```

auto accepts the dialogue but id like to confirm it actually appears, then verify some of the text contained within it, then accept it with a button click on OK.

Ive tried using various methods on the message option in the IDialog interface.
for instance

```
Page.Dialog += (_, dialog) =>  dialog.Message.Contains("Test");
```

This causes the test to hang, ( because nothing is closing the alert)

I also tried wrapping the above in an await Expect() statement but this did not work for me

Does anyone know a way to validate the text then move on to another action like clicking ok in order to dismiss the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a way to do this:

```
string message;
Page.Dialog += (_, dialog) =>
{
message = dialog.Message;
Assert.That(message, Is.SameAs("expected string"));
dialog.AcceptAsync();};
```